# Compensation decreased after recruiter fixed offer letter errors

Tags: job-offer, new-job, recruitment, legal, offer

My original offer mistakenly said it was for short term employment, thankfully after a lot of time, the internal recruiter had fixed it.

However, since a week has passed, she claims the stock values increased so she dropped my sign on bonus by a few thousand, and removed several of my stocks. She added a few thousand to my base pay, but it was only enough to make up for the lost bonus.

What's worse is contrary to what she said, the stock value dropped since my original offer, not increase, and also I don't understand how I could lose several stocks worth of value. She claims my overall compensation had increased by a few hundred from my previous offer, but all I'm seeing is that I lost a few thousand.

The delay is by no fault of mine. While I do like transferring some of my bonus to base pay, I don't like how she removed some of my stocks like that without even consulting me.

What's worse is she made the offer expire by tomorrow, I don't even know if I'll be able to get a hold of her. Originally she gave 5 days after sending the letter till expiry.

Not sure what I can do, I want the job but I feel exhausted dealing with this recruiter. If someone knows how stock value decrease means increased compensation please let me know.

Edit 2:
She extended the offer due date. Turns out they take the rolling average of the previous 3 weeks. It looks like she regenerated my offer when the stock's least performant week got dropped out of the average, which made the stock value go up, which made my other compensation numbers drop. She probably doesn't want to regenerate the offer next week because the rolling average would drop - it would maybe pick up this week's stock performance which wasn't good again.

Comment: Sounds like a classical cheat... 'only today! Quickquickquick!' - no good job is only available for a day.

Comment: 5 days is a very normal time for an offer to expire.

Comment: If the stock value increased you get the same amount of money for fewer stocks.

Comment: @DJClayworth, she ORIGINALLY gave 5 days.  When the offer was revised, the new offer apparently only had one (1) day before it pumpkin'ed.

Comment: Are these publicly traded shares?

Comment: Yes they are publicly traded.

Answer (score 8):

> Not sure what I can do, I want the job but I feel exhausted dealing
> with this recruiter.

You need to decide if you want the job at the current terms or not. The history of how the terms came into their current form is no longer relevant.

If you do want it, just accept.

If you don't want the job with the current terms, you can continue to negotiate, or just walk away and find a better job with better terms.

Answer (score 6):

If you are this burned out just from dealing with their recruiter, consider how you will feel when you learn that she is just doing the job her management is telling her to do, and they're ALL like that.

As Aganju pointed out in his comment, there is no such thing as a good job that is only available for one day.  Even the worst managers on the planet understand that there is such a thing as a 24-hour stomach bug, that can leave one seated on the porcelain throne while holding the plastic secondary waste receptacle, with special effects going at both ends.

You send her a very polite note, showing the daily stock chart (finance.yahoo.com is your FRIEND!) for the period in question, and saying "I thank you for getting the problems in the original offer fixed.  However, I frankly do not see how you came to the conclusion that the stock values increased while that was in progress, when the enclosed charts clearly say otherwise.  Taken as a whole, your revised offer is not satisfactory to me, and, as we do not have enough time for discussion before your revised offer expires, I must respectfully decline.  Should you wish to discuss this further, I may be reached at *contact address* or *telephone number*."

The above can probably be worded better.  The key points are that this is a new offer, it is not acceptable, and it is her own dam' fault that she didn't allow more time to discuss the matter.

It sounds to me as though she is giving you a golden opportunity, on a silver platter no less, to dodge a large-caliber bullet.  Take her up on it.  Or at least give her a chance to figure out that you didn't fall off the turnip truck yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that you can absorb the loss of stock shares, and benefit a lot more in the long run by working for this company as you can get valuable work experiences, improve your technical skills, and earn more money a few years down the road, then take the job offer.  (***We don't know which company it is and can't offer you good advice***).

If you think that this company is really weird from the way this recruiter treats you, and you believe that the company has no long term values or long term gains for you in terms of improving your work experiences and future salary increases, then you can decline the offer and look for another job elsewhere.

---

It is perplexing (or puzzling) that the recruiter is still negotiating, changing, and dictating the salary offer after giving you the original offer. I have not seen this in the US yet. Is it normal in your country for companies to do that ?